# Flutter StreamProvider with CloudFirestore causing error on Resume

Tags: flutter

Having a weird issue and cant seem to figure out if I have something setup wrong (new with Providers and streams) or if its a bug.  Everything seems to work fine except when the app resumes after being backed out with the back button, on Android, and then restarted.  Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch App
2. hit back button to close app (not just minimize)
3. Relaunch app

I get the following error:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 3566): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566): Process: com.crimsonowl.scryer, PID: 3566
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$DocumentObserver.onEvent(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:429)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$DocumentObserver.onEvent(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:402)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:504)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3566):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
I/Process ( 3566): Sending signal. PID: 3566 SIG: 9
```

After a lot of debugging and trying to figure out what was causing it.  Ive narrow the problem down to StreamProvider and my user data.  In my main screen I load a stream of the Users data with this:

```
return FutureProvider.value(
  value: Provider.of<IAPProvider>(context).initialize(),
  child: StreamProvider<User>.value(
    value: DatabaseProvider().streamUser(user.uid),
    child: MainScreen(),
  ),
);
```

And the code for the stream is this:

```
Stream<User> streamUser(String id) {
  return Firestore.instance
      .collection(USER_COLLECTION)
      .document(id)
      .snapshots()
      .map((snap) => User.fromFirestore(snap));
}
```

I figured out that anytime I try to write to the User document on the cloud firestore database the app crashes, but only when I have done the steps above.  On the initial launch (and works fine if I relaunch after it crashes) everything works as expected.  Something like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection(USER_COLLECTION).document(user.uid).updateData({'last_login': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
```

Comment: I'm getting the same crash with same repro steps.  It's also mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2434, but with no resolution.

Comment: I temporarily solved the issue by forcing a downgrading the firestore package in the pubspec.yaml file to this 'cloud_firestore: '0.13.4+2'